# does putty support SET_ANY_EVENT_MOUSE , if yes how enable it?

Tags: terminal, putty, nim-lang

i'm adding mouse support to a ncurses like library
and i'm sending the control sequence:

`SET_ANY_EVENT_MOUSE (1003h)` but it seems putty does not support it?

It *does* support `SET_BTN_EVENT_MOUSE (1002h)`

All other terminals i tried (xterm, vte bases terminals, iterm) working just fine.
Does putty also support `SET_ANY_EVENT_MOUSE` and must i enable something else?

How would you debug such kind control sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at PuTTY's source code, which is in a Git repository.  The relevant place to look is in `terminal.c` in the `toggle_mode` function.  The switch/case statement is ordered by mode number:

```c
      case 1000:                   /* xterm mouse 1 (normal) */
        term->xterm_mouse = state ? 1 : 0;
        win_set_raw_mouse_mode(term->win, state);
        break;
      case 1002:                   /* xterm mouse 2 (inc. button drags) */
        term->xterm_mouse = state ? 2 : 0;
        win_set_raw_mouse_mode(term->win, state);
        break;
      case 1006:                   /* xterm extended mouse */
        term->xterm_extended_mouse = state;
        break;
      case 1015:                   /* urxvt extended mouse */
        term->urxvt_extended_mouse = state;
        break;
      case 1047:
```

and as you see, it does nothing for **`1003`** (nor does the log mention it anywhere).

I'd link to the source, but the host doesn't respond at the moment.  However, from my local copy, I see the **`1002`** feature was added here:

```
commit 93101b5a716c3464789ecf5af6403c68559afa43
Author: Simon Tatham <anakin@pobox.com>
Date:   Sun May 6 14:20:41 2001 +0000

    Wez Furlong's patch to add xterm mouse reporting and proper mouse
    wheel support.

    [originally from svn r1097]

diff --git a/terminal.c b/terminal.c
```

so it's not a recently-overlooked issue.